# convert array of letters to array of words using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

convert array of letters to array of words using JavaScript

> const inputArr = [
> 'b', 'a', 'k', 'e', '',
> 'c', 'a', 'k', 'e', '',
> 'e', 'a', 't'
> ];
> and my desired output is :
> output = ['bake','cake','eat'];

I used Join method but I am not getting desired output.
const inputArr = [
'b', 'a', 'k', 'e', '',
'c', 'a', 'k', 'e', '',
'e', 'a', 't'
];

```
    const result=inputArr.join('');
    console.log(result);
```

output: "bakecakeeat"

Comment: Do you have control over the input? Is that something you wrote?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the answer in different way other than Join.

You can iterate over the inputArr then keep appending the character until you found the empty space(''), there you can add the word in the outputArr and and reset the word.

```js
const inputArr = [ 'b', 'a', 'k', 'e', '', 'c', 'a', 'k', 'e', '', 'e', 'a', 't' ];
var outputArr = [];
var word = '';
// Iterate over the array.
for (let i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
  if(inputArr[i]=='') {
    // If you found the empty Space(''), add to the outputArr
    outputArr.push(word);
    // reset the word, to start making the new word.
    word = '';
    // No need to execute the below code, so continue.
    continue;
  }
  // Keep appending the character to the word.
  word = word.concat(inputArr[i]);
}
// This is for the last word string.
if(word != '') {
 outputArr.push(word);
}
console.log(outputArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use

```
const inputArr = [ 'b', 'a', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'c', 'a', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'e', 'a', 't' ];
```

Note the difference between `''` and `' '`.

Comment: This could easily have been closed as a typo.

Comment: This all assumes that OP has control over the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have control over the input you can change the array to fit the other answer's method:

```js
    const inputArr = [ 'b', 'a', 'k', 'e', '', 'c', 'a', 'k', 'e', '', 'e', 'a', 't' ];

    inputArr.forEach((element, index) => {
      if(element === '') {
        inputArr[index] = ' ';
      }
    });
    
const result = inputArr.join('');
    
console.log(result)
```

Comment: ["b", "a", "k", "e", " ", "c", "a", "k", "e", " ", "e", "a", "t"].this is not the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`

```
inputArr.reduce((prev,curr) => {
    if (curr === '') {
        prev.push('');
    } else {
        prev[prev.length - 1] += curr;
    }
    return prev;
}, [''])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the input, You should replace `''` with `' '`, Then can do the following,

```js
const inputArr = [ 'b', 'a', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'c', 'a', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'e', 'a', 't' ];
const output = inputArr.join('').split(' ');
console.log(output);
```

**IF NOT** You can follow this,

```js
const inputArr = [ 'b', 'a', 'k', 'e', '', 'c', 'a', 'k', 'e', '', 'e', 'a', 't' ];
const output = inputArr.map( letter => letter === '' ? ' ':letter).join('').split(' ');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your given array, you want to join the letters and return an array of words, correct me if I am wrong.

So here is my solution for a given problem.

```js
const inputArr = [ 'b', 'a', 'k', 'e', '', 'c', 'a', 'k', 'e', '', 'e', 'a', 't' ];

let result = inputArr.map(item => item === '' ? ' ' : item).join('').split(' ');

console.log(result);
```

If you don't have control over input, then you can simply replace '' with ' ' and split it, period.